# Get emacs to open customize-group windows in -other-window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to force emacs to always open customize-group windows in -other-window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are we talking about the `widget-button-click` that gets activated after clicking on preferences and then trying to select a sub-group?

Answer (score 1):

You said:

*I know about that function. But clicking on customize in the menu runs `customize-group` not `customize-group-other-window`. I want `customize-group` to be an alias for `customize-group-other-window` –- MDCore Sep 30 '10 at 9:23*

If that is really what you want then just do it:

```
(defalias 'customize-group 'customize-group-other-window)
```

But I would guess that you don't really want to alias the *commands*, but rather you just want to remap the key bindings.  If that is the case, this is the answer:

```
(global-set-key [remap customize-group] 'customize-group-other-window)
```

That remaps all "keys" that were bound to `customize-group`, including menu item `Options` > `Customize` > `Customize Group`, to command `customize-group-other-window`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special function for this:

> customize-group-other-window is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `cus-edit.el'.
>
> (customize-group-other-window
>   &optional GROUP)
>
> Customize GROUP, which must be a
>   customization group, in another
>   window.

Comment: I know about that function. But clicking on customize in the menu runs `customize-group` not `customize-group-other-window`. I want `customize-group` to be an alias for `customize-group-other-window`

Answer (score 0):

Look at `special-display-regexps`.

There are a couple options that might work:

1. Specify an entry like `(REGEXP FRAME-PARAMETERS)` with `(same-frame . t)`. I don't know if this will necessarily use a different window (in contrast to `(same-window . t)`).
2. Specify an entry like `(REGEXP FUNCTION OTHER-ARGS)` where the FUNCTION argument is `customize-group-other-window`. It's normally used with a new frame, so you might have to play with the `special-display-function` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ***dedicated*** window for `*Help*` then clicking the `Customize` link will always use another window.